# Android clip/crop view content

Tags: android, view, glsurfaceview

I'm currently in the process of porting an existing iOS app over to Android and have run into a snag where I need to crop the contents of a view in my layout.

In iOS I was simply accessing the layer of the view and then setting `layer.contentsRect` accordingly.

In Android, I thought I had found an equivalent function of the GLSurfaceView class - `setClipBounds`, but this only works on devices with support for API level 18 and throws a `NoSuchMethodError` exception on my Galaxy S 3.

Does anyone have an alternative solution (or support library) for clipping or cropping the view contents for API level 9 (2.3)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here's some cropping code i wrote in xamarin (c#) it was ported from Java, you'll need to do the conversion on your own, the class names are roughly the same and the methods and properties are exposed as get/set in Java.

the code crops a bitmap to a circle, similar to facebook floating faces :)

```
    public static class BitmapHelpers
{
    public static Bitmap LoadAndResizeBitmap (this string fileName, int width, int height)
    {
        // First we get the the dimensions of the file on disk
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
        BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (fileName, options);

        // Next we calculate the ratio that we need to resize the image by
        // in order to fit the requested dimensions.
        int outHeight = options.OutHeight;
        int outWidth = options.OutWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (outHeight > height || outWidth > width) {
            inSampleSize = outWidth > outHeight
                               ? outHeight / height
                               : outWidth / width;
        }

        // Now we will load the image and have BitmapFactory resize it for us.
        options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (fileName, options);

        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap GetCroppedBitmap (Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (bitmap.Width,
                                     bitmap.Height, global::Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas (output);

        int color = -1;
        Paint paint = new Paint ();
        Rect rect = new Rect (0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        canvas.DrawARGB (0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.Color = Color.White;

        canvas.DrawCircle (bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2,
            bitmap.Width / 2, paint);
        paint.SetXfermode (new PorterDuffXfermode (global::Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
        canvas.DrawBitmap (bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```